# AppCache app prompts for internet access - Safari on iOS 7.0.1+ issues additional GET requests

Tags: ios7, mobile-safari, html5-appcache

I am building an offline AppCache app.

When I launch the app by clicking a home screen icon I get these 3 requests:

```
[18/Nov/2013:13:33:53 +0100] "GET /tso/cache.manifest HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11B554a"

[18/Nov/2013:13:34:00 +0100] "GET /tso/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png HTTP/1.1" 200 18482 "-" "Web/1.0 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0"

[18/Nov/2013:13:34:00 +0100] "GET /tso/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1136.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Web/1.0 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0"
```

When offline, iPhone prompts me to disable airplane mode or turn on WiFi. Other than that, the app works just fine.

Any idea what are those two other CFNetwork requests and how to either disable them or make them use the cached, offline assets? I believe iOS 6 and earlier versions of iOS 7 didn't have this behavior.

Thank you